# How to update a jtable from a different form?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdialog

```
public class A extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener
{
   private JTable table;
   private JButton button;

   public A()
   {
      button = new JButton("Load Dialog");
      button.addActionListener(this);

      initializeTable();
   }

   public void initializeTable()
   {

      table = new JTable();
      MyTableModel mymodel = new MyTableModel();

      table.setModel(mymodel);
   }

   public void changeModel(NewTableModel model)
   {
      table.setModel(model);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(null,true);
      dialog.setVisible(true);
   }
}

public class MyDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener
{

   private JButton button;

   public MyDialog(JFrame parent,bool modal)
   {
      button = new JButton("Change Model");
      button.addActionListener(this);

      super(parent,modal);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      NewTableModel newModel = new NewTableModel();
      A a = new A();

      a.changeModel(newModel);
   }
}
```

I want to update the table from the first form(A) in the second form(MyDialog). I want to set a new model for it that when I clicked the change model button in MyDialog it will automatically update the model in the first form(A) and all its displayed values will be replaced by the new model coming from MyDialog. How is it possible to do that? Hopefully someone can guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the model in `A` completly with the model from the `MyDialog`, why not provide a getter in `MyDialog` that returns the new model and simply replace in `A` once the dialog closes (assuming it's a modal dialog), otherwise you will need to pass a reference of `A` to `MyDialog`